# Where redfivelabs net60 Framework?

Tags: .net, symbian

I'm trying to build application for Nokia Symbian

by .NET Framework (C#)

I read about redfivelabs net60 Framework

but I not find Their website!!

Are there other ways to build applications on Nokia Symbian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Red Five Labs have closed. Their website is down, it was last updated in [2009](http://wayback.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.redfivelabs.com/). You may be able to find some copies of their Net60 .NET framework on the download sites (via Google), but I doubt it will work with the latest Symbian devices and you won't get any support.

---

Yes, there are other way to build applications for Symbian. One way is using native Symbian  C++, but the best way now is to use Qt (pronounced "cute", not QT).

Also, Qt applications can easily run on MeeGo devices (like the new Nokia N9 and N950) and also Nokia have just announced Qt will be available on their "Next Billion" phones. So there will be plenty of deployment opportunities. Qt and QML development is also much easier than native Symbian C++.

Head over to [Nokia Developer](https://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/) for SDKs and getting started guides.